# Rotary encoder and PLC ( Orbit Merret OMC 8000)

Tags: plc

I have Orbit Merret PLC OMC 8000 and I need to use rotary encoder with it. But there is almost no documentation. Does anybody know how to do it? I'm programming the PLC in MULTIPROG (the program given with the PLC).
Thanks.

Comment: Data sheet and user manual for the OMC 8000 are on [the product page](http://www.merret.cz/en/produkty/plc/zakladni-modul/omc-8000).

Comment: @BenMiller but these files are completely useless. Datasheet provides inly tech specs, manual says only how to set it up, but nothing more. Examples provided by IDE uses just regular inputs. The PLC has 2 inputs for encoders, but nowhere is said how to use it.